# Laravel Eloquent - How Can I Sum fields inside relation's column?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
  I need to sum every paid_amount inside of each expense_payment_liab instead of returning all these 
 individual  paid_amount  as it can be seen in images for clear view.So far my query looks like this:
 Model Relation is like Voucher has many Expenses and Expenses has many Expensepaymentliab.       

  This is so far what I tried:
    $expense = Voucher::where('voucher_date', $request->date)
        ->where('account_id', 1)
        ->with(['expenses' => function ($expense) use ($date) {
            $expense->with(['expPaymentLiab' => function ($inner) use ($date) {
                return $inner->select('paid_amount', 'expense_id')->where('paid_date', '=', $date);
                //need to return the sum of paid_amount.
                // I've  also tried this
                 //$inner->sum('paid_amount')
                // $inner->sum('paid_amount', 'expense_id')
             }]);
            $expense->select('id', 'date', 'total_amount', 'voucher_id');
        }])->get();
```

[These are the images please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbbNx.png)

[Need to sum such paid_amount field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93V07.png)

Comment: use sum(total_amount)

Comment: Not possible sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withCount` to sum the `paid_amount` field.

```php
Voucher::where('voucher_date', $request->date)
        ->where('account_id', 1)
        ->with(['expenses' => function ($expense) use ($date) {
            // select the columns first, so the subquery column can be added later.
            $expense->select('id', 'date', 'total_amount', 'voucher_id');
            $expense->withCount(['expPaymentLiab AS paid_sum' => function ($query) use ($date) {
                return $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(paid_amount)'))->where('paid_date', '=', $date);
             }]);
        }])
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks sir. It worked. And Sir can we select another field after DB::raw('SUM(paid_amount)'', _____, _____) in these blank spaces.

Comment: @Diwashv1 if you want to get the other fields you can use `with(function($q) { return $q->groupBy('expense_id')->selectRaw('SUM(paid_amount), expense_id, ________')})`. Remember to select the foreign_key.

Comment: Sir when using this, I got an error :
 Arguement 2 on selectRaw must be an array.(Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given).

Comment: @Diwashv1 `with(['expPaymentLiab' =>function($q) { return $q->groupBy('expense_id')->selectRaw('SUM(paid_amount), expense_id, ________');}])` I forgot the `['expPaymentLiab'`

Comment: No sir it worked, I wrote it with (['expPaymentLiab' .. line , but actually I made a mistake here:
>selectRaw('SUM(paid_amount)),  'expense_id');}]). So warning was about second parameter to be array and in this case, it was nt an array. 
Thanks for quick reply though :)